# dropped.value does dropped.id exist?

Tags: javascript

I would like image.src to display the id not the value of each `<option>`. Does dropped.id exist? Can this be done? Or is the id locked in the `<select>`? When the user hits submit, I need to pass the value in the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function swapImage(){ 
      var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap"); 
      var dropped = document.getElementById("changethisimage"); 
      image.src = "http://foo.com/images/"+dropped.value; 
}; 
</script> 
<img id="imageToSwap" src="http://foo.com/images/SHOP_Car Emblem.jpg" width="150" align=right> 
<select name="os0" id="changethisimage" onChange="swapImage()"> 
<option value="Light Blue" id="SHOP_Car Emblem_Cyan.jpg" selected>Light Blue 
<option value="Dark Blue" id="SHOP_Car Emblem_DkBlue.jpg">Dark Blue 
<option value="Canadian Red" id="SHOP_Car Emblem_Red.jpg">Canadian Red 
<option value="Irish Green" id="SHOP_Car Emblem_IrishGreen.jpg">Irish Green 
</select>
```

Comment: Try closing your `<option>` tags...

Comment: You also should not have spaces in your id values.

Comment: Google for html data attributes, it's preferred than passing url as an id

Comment: Don't use `id` attributes to store those values. If you don't want to use the `value` attributes (Why not?), you can define custom data attributes like `data-src`. For instance: `<option value="Light Blue" data-src="SHOP_Car Emblem_Cyan.jpg">Light Blue</option>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

`image.src = "url" + dropped.selectedOptions[0].id`

Browser support may be bad however. So you may want this

```
var selected = dropped.selectedIndex;
image.src= "url" + dropped.options[selected].id
```

See the [Select](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-select-element) interface for more details.

As a side-note, I see your doing

`<select name="os0" id="changethisimage" onChange="swapImage()">`

The `onChange="code"` bit is bad, really bad. It's an in-line event handler. This means you have a piece of JavaScript code in your HTML. This totally goes against separation of concerns and leads to spaghetti code hell.

You should totally replace it with

`document.getElementById("changethisimage").addEventListener("change", swapImage);`

Comment: Why is `onchange` `"bad, really bad"`?

Comment: @Neal good point, I explained the whole separations of concerns thing.

Comment: @Raynos i agree, but on SO if the OP dons't ask for optimization it may not be relevant.

Comment: @Neal it should of been Raynos

Comment: @david If someone uses bad code, I'm going to tell them its bad code. I may have to maintain it one day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JS:

```
function swapImage(selectObj){ 
      var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
      var options = selectObj.options;
      var sIndex = selectObj.selectedIndex; 
      image.src = "http://foo.com/images/"+options[sIndex].id; 
};
```

HTML: `<select name="os0" id="changethisimage" onChange="swapImage(this)">`

Comment: true.. but you should fix it!

Comment: @Raynos and you didn't because....? I can dv for the same reason, but I did not because your answer is perfectly viable ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

HTML:

```
<select id="select_kitten">
    <option value="Kitten 1" data-src="210/200/" selected>Kitten 1</option>
    <option value="Kitten 2" data-src="220/210/">Kitten 2</option>
    <option value="Kitten 3" data-src="200/180/">Kitten 3</option>
    <option value="Kitten 4" data-src="225/220/">Kitten 4</option>
</select>

<img id="kitten_img">
```

JavaScript:

```
var img = document.getElementById( 'kitten_img' ),
    select = document.getElementById( 'select_kitten' );

function onchange() {
    img.style.opacity = 0.2;
    img.src = 'http://placekitten.com/' + select.options[ select.selectedIndex ].dataset.src;
}

img.onload = function () {
    this.style.opacity = 1;
};

select.onchange = onchange;
onchange();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XmhU9/4/

`dataset` isn't implemented in IE though. If you require support for IE, consider a cross-browser library.